# How to calculate prediction intervals based on Chebyshev inequality?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, error, prediction-interval

I have recently read the article by Gardner (1988) who proposes Chebyshev inequality-based prediction intervals for forecast:

> suppose we have a model selected on the usual basis of one-step-ahead
>   fit. One pass through the data is made to compute the variance of the
>   fitted errors at one-step-ahead. A second pass is made to compute the
>   variance at two-steps-ahead. It is important to understand that the
>   forecasting model is not re-estimated. We simply make two-step-ahead
>   forecasts with the same model and compute the variance of the fitted
>   errors. This process is continued until an individual variance is
>   computed for each desired leadtime. (...)
>   The second step in the procedure is to compute standard errors at each
>   leadtime. The final step is to apply a multiplier to each standard
>   error that yields the desired prediction intervals. The multiplier is
>   based on the Chebyshev inequality (...)

The description is pretty vague, so I would like to ask how exactly such intervals are calculated? Say I have black-box forecasting function $b_h(x_1,...,x_n)$ that uses $x_1,...,x_n$ datapoints to produce forecast $\hat x_{n+1},...,\hat x_{n+h}$, how would I apply this method to assess PI's for the forecast?

---

Gardner, E.S. (1988). A simple method of computing prediction intervals for time series forecasts. Management Science, 34(4), 541-546.